# Xamarin - CustomRenderer doesn't render controls

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

So I made a CustomRenderer for my Android part of my app. This CustomRenderer is located in MyProject.Droid and it's called CustomSwitchRenderer which, obviously, is meant for the switches I'm using. So when I tried to test it the switches wouldn't show up in my page. It was just a blank tabbed page with two navigation buttons in it. I find this very wierd since no errors and warnings are being thrown. This is what I have:

The Page:

```
        private  void Doelen() {
        pages.Add (new ContentPage {
            Title="Doelen",
            BackgroundImage="background.jpg",
            Content = new StackLayout {
                Padding = 15,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                Opacity = 0.75,
                Children = {
                    new Label {
                        Text = subjects [2],
                        FontSize = 30,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                        TextColor = Color.White
                    },
                    new Label {
                        Text = "Omzet:",
                        FontSize = 16
                    },
                    ckbOmzet,
                    ckbMarge,
                    ckbNieuwelant,
                    new StackLayout { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, Children = { navButtonPrev, navButtonNext } }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

and this is how I defined my switches:

```
private Switch ckbOmzet = new Switch();
private Switch ckbMarge = new Switch();
private Switch ckbNieuwelant = new Switch();
```

and ofcourse, my CustomSwitchRenderer class which is located in MyProject.Droid:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Switch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.Droid
{
public class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.TextOn = "AAN";
            Control.TextOff = "UIT";

            Control.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
        }

        this.SetNativeControl(Control);
    }
}
}
```

I have looked at multiple threads and I still don't know what's I'm doing wrong here! Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:

The controls are being rendered now, but the TextOn and TextOff property doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure your problem is on the renderer? You stated your page just showed the navigation controls, but I can see there are two labels and a background image. Are you sure you loaded and pushed the page?

Comment: yes I'm sure that I loaded the page because when I tap the tab of that page it navigates to it. I also think that it's the renderer or the method how I implemented the renderer because every other page loads just fine.

Comment: If you remove the switches the page shows the labels?

Comment: For some reason, no. But the other pages load their labels just fine.

Comment: Then the problem isn't on the renderer, if the controls aren't added to the page the renderer does nothing... try to set to your root stacklayout HroizontalOptions and VerticalOptions of FillAndExpand, just to check if it's a problem with the layout size calculation.

Comment: It isn't the size which is causing the problem, just checked it.

Comment: Well, then for a problem like yours I would start a new blank page, add one by one each control and test until the labels disappear, with that you then can start debugging, without knowing what causes your problem is very hard to seek a solution.

Comment: Even the labels aren't showing when I remove the switches, eventhough I've implemented labels like this on every page, where they actually show up, but for some reason they don't want to show up now.

Comment: Have you tried to start with a new blank page and add one by one the controls and test? Sometimes is faster to start from the ground (specially in cases where you don't have a lot of code) than try to find what's failing...

Comment: Do you see something if you add `Control.Text = "Test";` to your renderer?

Comment: Yes I do, and the label problem is now fixed. The control says Test

Comment: ok, and if you add now a switch does it render (I would add label->switch->label, to have something which delimits upper and lower bounds of the switch)?

Comment: nope, the switch still doesn't show up

Comment: GOT IT! it was the drawable state, but there's one more problem. The TextOn property doesn't work

Comment: Don't call this.SetNativeControl(Control); as it has already been called.

Comment: Thats weird, the same thing worked in a native project but here I have the same issue...